# How to merge pandas series and add common values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two Pandas series (`pandas.core.series.Series`) which I want to merge into one single Series, adding the values on common keys as such :

```
series1:
AAA Championship Car season                                       1
Act of Parliament of Ontario                                      1
Act of Parliament of the United Kingdom                          18
Act of Parliament of the United Kingdom election law              1
```

+

```
series2:
ATP Buenos Aires                                                  1
ATP World Tour Finals                                             1
Act of Parliament of British Columbia                             1
Act of Parliament of the United Kingdom                          18
Act of Parliament of the United Kingdom election law              1
```

=

```
series3:
AAA Championship Car season                                       1
ATP Buenos Aires                                                  1
ATP World Tour Finals                                             1
Act of Parliament of British Columbia                             1
Act of Parliament of Ontario                                      1
Act of Parliament of the United Kingdom                          36
Act of Parliament of the United Kingdom election law              2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `pd.concat` with `sum`:

```
series3 = pd.concat([series1,series2]).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
0
AAA Championship Car season                              1
ATP Buenos Aires                                         1
ATP World Tour Finals                                    1
Act of Parliament of British Columbia                    1
Act of Parliament of Ontario                             1
Act of Parliament of the United Kingdom                 36
Act of Parliament of the United Kingdom election law     2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

```
full_df = (
    pd.concat([series1, series2], axis = 0)
      .groupby(level=0)
      .sum()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.Series.sum()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html
that also provides a way to fill in missing values.

For instance, your code could be

```
series3 = series1.add(series2, fill_value=0)
```